# LWC styling for iOS - lightning input is going off the screen

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightninginput

I've experienced a strange problem on Salesforce app for iOS. I have LWC component with searchbox. It's a standard `lightning-input` and search result list as an `ul` element with `li` as options.
On desktop it works correctly for all resolutions, on iPad too, but in case of iPhones it behaves really weird. When the input is empty everything is fine.
[image: Search]

But if I type in some text and additional div appears under the search the whole input and result list is expanding out of the screen.

[image]

I've tried to set on all elements `max-width: 100`, but it didn't help. What could cause this strange behaviour and how can i force it to not expand out of the screen? Both for input and search results. Why is it changing only if I'm typing some text?

Pseudocode of my solution...

```
<lightning-layout>
   <lightning-layout-item size=12">
     Title...
     <lightning-layout>
          <lightning-layout-item size="12">
           <!-- RADIO BUTTON AND ITS LABEL -->
          </lightning-layout-item>
          <lightning-layout-item size="12">
             <lightning-input .... />
          </lightning-layout-item>
          <lightning-layout-item size="12">
               <!-- RESULT LIST - ALL OF THIS CONTENT IS IN A SEPARATE COMPONENT -->
              <ul>
                 <li>Some result</li>
                 <li>Some result</li>
              </ul>
          </lightning-layout-item>
     </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
```

Comment: You will need to include some code in order for us to help, since we'll need to reproduce the problem in order to troubleshoot it. Can you make a minimum viable reproduction (MVR) or a [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground) to demonstrate the issue, or at least share the code?

Comment: P.S. My immediate guess is that the UL/LI are in the same container as the search box, so when you type, the UL/LI bounding boxes are causing everything to expand. The issue will probably require another inner container with the max-width constraints in order to prevent things from flowing outside the box.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, thanks for your answer. I've included overall view of this part of the component. In the meantime I'll try to reproduce this in a playground but I'm not sure if it will be possible as above code doesn't work on Salesforce app only. On desktop in each resolution it works correctly. As you can see, I have a result in a separate container, so I'm not sure why it still behaves so strange.